# Failed to get broadcast_22_piece0 of broadcast_22

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, spark-graphx

when I run Scala application on Spark cluster in yarn mode(spark version 2.2.0),the application is using the pregel model, each vertex in the data graph sends message. the Exception information as follows:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 29 in stage 25.0 failed 4 times, 
most recent failure: Lost task 29.3 in stage 25.0 (TID 1632, 192.168.1.5, executor 1): java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException:
Failed to get broadcast_22_piece0 of broadcast_22
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1310)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_22_piece0 of broadcast_22
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:178)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:150)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:222)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1303)
        ... 12 more
```

I have searched the exception online, and one of the suggestions is adding statement `.set("spark.cleaner.ttl","2000")`
but it still does not work well.
Can you help me? thanks a lot.

some sinnpets that may cause the above exception as follows:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://node01.:7077").appName("ioce").getOrCreate()
.......
and in the program, joining dataframe is used(which I looked through online warns that may be also relevant to the exception).
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code you used?